# Android PlusClient share image

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

Hey I'm trying to share ling with image to user's google+ feed, so I am using PlusShare:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .setText("Some text")
                        .setContentUrl("http://example.com/images/image.png")
                        .getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

My problem is that the image attached to the post isn't my `http://example.com/images/image.png` but the some image at the root page `http://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

From the Google+ documentation:

"A post to Google+ that includes a link renders a preview, or snippet, that contains the page title, a brief description of the page, and a thumbnail image. These pieces of data are extracted from the shared URL's content in one of four ways, listed in order of precedence:

1. Schema.org microdata (recommended)
2. OpenGraph protocol
3. Title and meta "description" tags
4. Best guess from page content (not recommended)"

For more information, or to see what a particular URL will look like when shared, you can use the [Snippet tool](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) in the Google+ documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *attach* a full-sized image to your post rather than link to an image (and hope it gets your thumbnail correct), you can use the `addStream()` as demonstrated in [Ian Barber's recent post](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/10/attaching-images-to-google-shares-on.html):

```
public void onClickShare(View v) {
  Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  photoPicker.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(photoPicker, REQ_SELECT_PHOTO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(requestCode == REQ_SELECT_PHOTO) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
      ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
      String mime = cr.getType(selectedImage);

      PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setText("Some text")
        .addStream(selectedImage)
        .setType(mime);
      startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), REQ_START_SHARE);
    }
  }
}
```